# What need to do to copy Netbeans project on server?

Tags: postgresql, netbeans7.0

I have problem regarding on netbeans project. I had build the project using netbeans on localhost. It run smoothly on localhost, but when I try copy this netbeans project to the company server it cannot be run as like on localhost. On the server, not has netbeans. Is it possible to run my netbeans project on server that have no netbeans?

If yes, how is it?Please help me..

On my local machine I have netbeans, use tomcat and database postgres and at company server have java, jdk and database postgres.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Though the question is vague I will try to answer it.
First of all, if you are creating a standard web project using netbeans then you should be able to right click on your project name and create a war file. In the output window you will see where the war file is created.

Now move your war file on the server, server will need a tomcat.

Copy the war file in TOMCAT_HOME\webapps dir and restart the tomcat.

If you see a new dir created under webapps with the same name as you war file then you have successfully deployed your project.

Still there are no guarantees that it will work there because you might have other issues related to db connection etc.
Thanks

Comment: Ok I had try your step just now. Actually, the process is user need to login in the page and then it will check in database postgres whether the data is there.If user success their login, they can view the other page member. When I run on localhost which is http://localhost:8080/work/index.html it really work and login success. But when I put on server and test the program www.abc.com/work/index.html the page appear, but the user cannot login. After user submit the login the http error 405 is appear. What's wrong with that?

Comment: I can run it using localhost on the server machine with http://localhost:8080/work. But, it still not work when I put my work in folder in server that was created by company and type on browser with www.abc.com/work. The login I check with postgres database and it also has postgres on server. In database already has the data username and password.